# Rspec binding.pry from method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pry, binding.pry

I'm trying to use binding.pry on method and debug it.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

hello.rb

```
class Hello
 def self.hello
  'Hello world!'
  binding.pry
 end
end
```

spec/hello_spec.rb

```
describe Hello do
 it 'Hello#hello should print message' do
  expect {Hello.hello}.to eq('Hello world!')
 end
end
```

I would like to debug self.hello method, how could I log this method using binding.pry? When I try to run rspec hello_spec.rb I don't get pry console to debug that method.

Comment: Any error raised? BTW,  `print` will return `nil`, so `expect {Hello.hello}.to eq('Hello world!')` will failed.

Comment: I updated question. In example above no errors raised. I would expect pry console to open and be able to debug that method. I can add binding.pry to rspec "it" method and it works as expected.

Comment: Make sure you have added `pry` gems for `:test` group as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line:

```
expect {Hello.hello}.to eq('Hello world!')
```

to:

```
expect Hello.hello.to eq('Hello world!')
```

and it should work. In other words, remove the brackets. It worked for me.

I had to do some assumptions about your setup. I would recommend including your Gemfile next time that you have a question.

Comment: RSpecs `expect` can be used with `()` or `{}` (block syntax). When called with a parameter, the parameter is called/elaluated before the `eq` (@AutoVit  this is what you want i your case).
When expect is called with the block syntax, the block called during `eq`.

From the [docs](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.9/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Expectations.html): "The last form (the block form) is needed to match against ruby constructs that are not objects, but can only be observed when executing a block of code. This includes raising errors, throwing symbols, yielding, and changing values."